# HAVING and WHERE clause difference in SQL

Tags: sql, where-clause, having

As I've read everywhere, HAVING clause and WHERE clause performs a sort of similar function but the WHERE clause condition applies before grouping and the HAVING applies after. What exactly does this mean? What if I don't group them before hand? Do I just get the same results?

Answer (score 0):

Most databases do not really support `having` with no `group by`.  So, the difference between the two is really simple.  You can use aggregation functions in `having`.  They cause a syntax error in `where`.  Really simple.  Can't make a mistake.

I am guessing that you are using MySQL.  This database extends the use of `having`.  It allows it in *non-aggregation* queries, which is highly non-standard.  In doing so, it allows the use of table aliases in the condition.

So this generates an error (assuming that `x.foo` is not a column):

```
select x.col as foo
from x
where foo = 3;
```

However, this is allowed *in MySQL*:

```
select x.col as foo
from x
having foo = 3;
```

In other databases, this would generate a syntax error.

This is a convenience.  In most databases, you would use a subquery (which you can still do in MySQL) or a CTE (which is now allowed in MySQL 8.0).